# Настройка столбца Оценка в Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

Я добавил через параметры списка возможность назначать оценки элементам и выбрал систему голосования "Нравится".
Вопрос в следующем: как изменить столбец оценки, а точнее убрать появляющиеся смайлики при нажатии на кнопку "нравится" и изменить текст самих кнопок "нравится/не нравится"

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0):

Невозможно выполнить указанные в вопросе действия без написания кода.

Для скрытия иконки можно добавить css `.ms-comm-likesImgContainer {display: none;}`
Стиль можно добавить непосредственно на страницу представления списка и формы элемента или добавить в Master page в случае, если нужно скрыть на всем узле.

Если иконку нужно заменить на другую - это можно сделать путем добавления кода в Master page. Master page конечно нужно создать новую(можно на основе существующих). Редактирование стандартных SharePoint Master pages(seattle, oslo) не допускается. Подробнее о том как заменить изображение описано в [блоге Elio Struyf](https://www.eliostruyf.com/customize-star-rating-images-sharepoint-2013/).

```
_spPageContextInfo.themedImageFileNames = { "RatingsSmallStarFilled.png": 
"RatingsSmallStarFilled.png", "RatingsSmallStarEmpty.png": 
"RatingsSmallStarEmpty.png", "RatingsSmallStarLeftHalfFilled.png": 
"RatingsSmallStarLeftHalfFilled.png", "RatingsSmallStarRightHalfFilled.png": 
"RatingsSmallStarRightHalfFilled.png", "RatingsSmallStarHoveroverEmpty.png": 
"RatingsSmallStarHoveroverEmpty.png", "RatingsSmallStarHoveroverFilled.png": 
"RatingsSmallStarHoveroverFilled.png", "RatingsLargeStarFilled.png": 
"RatingsLargeStarFilled.png"};
if (_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl === "/") {
  _spPageContextInfo.themedCssFolderUrl = "/Your-Image-Location";
} else {
  _spPageContextInfo.themedCssFolderUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/Your-Image-Location";
}
```

Замена текста кнопки может бы произведена путем добавление нехитрого JS кода в мастер страницу или на страницу представления и формы списка.